# Why is FileStream not closed by XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, xmlreader

So I am using the `FileStream` inside `XmlReader`

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open), readerSettings))
{
    reader.close()
}
```

However, the file feed into the `XmlReader` is still in the lock state after the `using` scope, weird, I thought the `XmlReader` is going to close the `FileStream` for me, is it not?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
using(var stream = new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open))
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, readerSettings))
{

}
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that explicitly stated that the `XmlReader` would call dispose on the underlying stream when it was disposed.  Also, I always use it as shown above and I have never encountered a problem.

Browsing through reflector I also find no instances where it calls `Dispose()` on the stream when creating a `XmlTextReaderImpl`.  The `XmlTextReaderImpl` does not implement `Dispose()` and its `Close()` method looks like this:

```
internal void Close(bool closeInput)
{
    if (this.parsingFunction != ParsingFunction.ReaderClosed)
    {
        while (this.InEntity)
        {
            this.PopParsingState();
        }
        this.ps.Close(closeInput);
        this.curNode = NodeData.None;
        this.parsingFunction = ParsingFunction.ReaderClosed;
        this.reportedEncoding = null;
        this.reportedBaseUri = string.Empty;
        this.readState = ReadState.Closed;
        this.fullAttrCleanup = false;
        this.ResetAttributes();
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest, no. I thought XmlReader is like StreamReader, will close the inner stream once done. use two using statement is just a bit clumsy.

Comment: Anecdotal, but most of the examples I see use the two `using`'s.

Comment: @TOMMYWANG: Well you may think so, but I cannot find anywhere in the code (using reflector) where `XmlTextReaderImpl` (which is what `XmlReader.Create()` actually returns) disposes of the stream.  If it did close the stream you would run into problems when using one stream for multiple readers (what if I want to keep the stream alive?  Why should the reader decide that I can't?), so it takes the safe approach of doing nothing.  I don't agree that it is "clumsy', but 'clumsy' is better than 'broken'.

Comment: @TOMMYWANG: NP, glad to help :)

Comment: I'd rather an underlying stream *not* be closed by a reader because you may still want to use the stream afterwards, but can't since it would have been closed! So this is the best behavior IMO.

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to control this through XmlReaderSettings.CloseInput.

```
readerSettings.CloseInput = true;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open), readerSettings))
{
    // do work with the reader
}
```

Or, more concisely if you don't care about other reader settings:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.Open), new XmlReaderSettings() { CloseInput = true }))
{
    // do work with the reader
}
```

Comment: Good answer, this stops FxCop from complaining about multiple disposals if you set CloseInput = false, which was annoying me.

Comment: Isn't the reader.close() statement here redundant since exiting the using statement will call Dispose() and that calls Close()?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep track of the `FileStream` and the `XmlReader`.  It's potentially dangerous for the `XmlReader` to close the underlying stream.  In the case where the `FileStream` is used by multiple readers: if one of these readers were to close the stream this would cause the other readers to fail unexpectedly.

It's a bit of a pain since some stream readers and writers will close the underlying stream, while others don't.  As a best practice I always close and dispose of the streams I open manually.  This also helps mitigate some 'gotchas' with certain streams.
e.g. [You need to dispose a `GZipStream` before calling `.ToArray()`](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2008/01/24/118866.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but maybe this might help someone...

I tried Eric's method as it seemed like a good solution but I kept getting warning [CA2202](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182334.aspx) when I ran VS code analysis on it.

Near the bottom of [CA2202](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182334.aspx), Microsoft recommends to use the following:

(I slightly modified the it for "XmlReader".)

```
Stream stream = null;
try
{
    stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open);
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlReader (stream))
    {
        stream = null;
        // Use the reader object...
    }
}
finally
{
    if(stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

instead of...

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlReader (stream))
    {
        // Use the reader object...
    }
}
```

It is much longer but at least it does not throw any warnings.

Comment: This will cause the same incorrect behaviour of not actually disposing the stream at all, though, since the `XmlReader` doesn't dispose its stream by default for whatever reason.  The good news is that this particular warning doesn't seem to happen any more, so it looks like they fixed the false positive.