# VB.Net XMLTextWriter cannot access file because it is in use?

Tags: xml, vb.net, writer

I am writing an auto-updating function that reads the client version from XML and then after patching some files, an XMLTextWriter should update the client version, but when ever I try to create the TextWriter I am being told that the file is still in use even though I close the readers. What am I missing?

```
  'pulling in reader from xml'

  Dim clientReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("launch.xml")

    'Read the XML files to determine the server version'

    clientReader.ReadToFollowing("serverURL")
    Dim serverURL As String = clientReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
    Dim serverXMLpath As String = serverURL & "Updater/serverInfo.xml"
    Dim serverReader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(serverXMLpath)
    serverReader.ReadToFollowing("serverVer")
    Dim serverVer As Double = serverReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble()

    'Read client XML to determine clientVersion'
    clientReader.ReadToFollowing("clientVer")
    Dim clientVer As Double = clientReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble()

    'Determine what updates need to be downloaded'

    serverReader.ReadToFollowing("totalUpdates")
    Dim totalUpdates As Integer = serverReader.ReadElementContentAsInt()

    '.....'
    'files are downloaded and updated here'
    '.....'


    clientReader.Close()
    serverReader.Close()


    'change the client version!'
    Dim clientWriter As New XmlTextWriter("launch.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    'clientWriter.WriteElementString("clientVer", serverVer)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why filestream not closed by xmlreader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844978/why-filestream-not-closed-by-xmlreader)

Comment: try setting to nothing : clientReader = nothing serverReader = nothing

Comment: @jdweng I gave that a shot. The file is still being used by another process.

Comment: Both object has a ReadState().  Determine what the read state is : Closed, EndOfFile, Error, Initial, Interactive.

Comment: I checked the ReadState, it is listed as Interactive before closing and Closed when Close() is used. When the reader is set to Nothing, I am getting a NullReferenceException